# SharePoint 2010: Some values called in CommonViewFields are not appearing in CQWP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've created some custom fields to be displayed using the CommonViewFields for a Content Query Web Part. And amended the ItemStyle to reflect it as well. Now, the problem i have is that, some information are not being displayed.

To be exact, this is a task summary CQWP where i need the value of *title*, *due date*, *percentage complete* and the person *assigned to* the task to be available on the site. Everything is displaying properly, however, only some of the names are displayed for the *assigned to* field. Some of the tasks are not displaying the person it's *assigned to*.

I've double checked to make sure the type of field is correct in the content type.

Is there any reason for this? How can I overcome it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this happened. Surprisingly Content Query Web Part doesn't allow Multiple Selection (in the original List setting as this CQWP was pulling the data from a List available in the SharePoint site) for the value field. So all those names that were not appearing either had a few people assigned to it or had the Multiple Selection setting as 'Yes'.

After changing the setting to 'No', all the names appeared perfectly fine.

Now trying to find if there is a way to allow more values to be displayed.